# Dark liquid floating in secondary fermentor

Tags: beer, secondary-fermentation, trub, mold

I started the fermentation for a pale ale two and a half weeks ago, dry hopped it five days in and then racked it four days ago. The trub has fallen to the bottom and I just noticed a dark layer of liquid floating on the top. I've never seen this before. Does anyone have an idea of what it is?[image]

Comment: So I am not assuming anything here, but are you sure it isn't a trick of the light? Do you have a yeast flor that could be shading the fluid directly beneath it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain its beer ;)  Even a pale ale looks dark in a carboy when it clears.

Your yeast is settling to the bottom and in that process the beer at the top is clearing.  But this beer is having trouble clearing.  That looks like a lot of sediment for a secondary on a pale ale, to me.

My recommendation would be to crash cool it. That will help drop everything out of suspension there, leaving you with bright beer you can rack off.  Or just leave it be, I'm sure it will clear.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too.  Even if you have sediments at the bottom, the middle layer still seems to contain a lot of trub in suspension.  With time or cold crashing you should get more sediments at the bottom and more clear beer at the top.   You can also look at ways to clear you beer with some products.

Comment: So i guess now that you mention it and I look more closely I guess I was looking at it wrong. I was thinking the top layer was darker, where in fact is the lower body that has been lightened by the yeast in suspension. Yeah I think this is indeed the answer, the dark layer on top is the clean clear beer.